# Different groups from jenkins job's shell and bash on docker container

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins

I have installed jenkins master on a docker container and running a slave using the Swarm plugin within a docker container. I created a group within the docker slave. Once I enter the slave container using `docker exec -it <container> bash` and type `groups` my created group is correctly listed.

However, when I type `groups` into a job descriptions shell and execute the job on that created slave my group does not appear.

*Edit*:
Slave container: Simply starts a jenkins-slave as user `jenkins`. On startup the following code is executed (script: startup.sh)  via `CMD [ "/startup.sh" ]`. The `jenkins-slave.sh` is provided under https://gist.github.com/sfrehse/02c7d57fad862c71c20f07c59caba240.

```
DOCKER_SOCKET=/var/run/docker.sock
DOCKER_GROUP=dockergrp
JENKINS_USER=jenkins

if [ -S ${DOCKER_SOCKET} ]; then
    DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' ${DOCKER_SOCKET})
    sudo groupadd -for -g ${DOCKER_GID} ${DOCKER_GROUP}
    sudo usermod -aG ${DOCKER_GROUP} ${JENKINS_USER}
fi

/usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave.sh
```

After startup from bash: `docker exec -it 8b85afe2b360 groups` outputs `jenkins dockergrp`.

Triggering a job just containing the following code:

```
whoami
groups
docker ps
```

outputs

```
 jenkins
 jenkins
 Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker 
         daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get 
         http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.30/containers/json: dial 
         unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

The group `dockergrp` is missing in the second line.

Overall, I'm unable to access the docker daemon without `sudo` and the problem seems to be the missing group. Running the command `docker exec -it <id> docker ps` outputs my running containers successfully.

Comment: Print your container id and see if jenkins is running new containers and which images. How have you added groups as such? Using custom Dockerfile?

Comment: The container is definitely the created one. I ran `sudo groupadd -for -g <some-id> <grpName>` and finally `sudo usermod -aG <grpName> jenkins`.

Comment: Still not getting a clear picture of how everything is setup at your end

Comment: I just added some more information.

Comment: when you do docker exec -it <container> bash, what is the visible bash user?

Comment: I just run `docker exec` for debugging. The user is `jenkins`.

Comment: How is executed the startup script? What jenkins-slave.sh does?

Comment: Added description of the startup script. The `jenkins-slave.sh` starts the Jenkins Swarm plugin using `java -jar ...`.

Comment: What are the uid of jenkins user in salve and jenkins user in master?

Comment: Try changing the last line to this: `sudo su -l jenkins -c /usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave.sh `. There is a known issue when adding groups that are not reloaded

Comment: Your suggestion solves the problem. :-) Thanks. Please add the answer to get the points.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :) You're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue when adding groups, they are not reloaded for already logged-in users.

Try changing the last line to this:

```
sudo su -l jenkins -c /usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave.sh
```

In order to launch the script under a new fresh jenkins login.

Note: You can prepend an `exec` instruction in order to not have a child process, so just replace the current one:

```
exec sudo su -l jenkins -c /usr/local/bin/jenkins-slave.sh
```